# Google Optimize not working with Activation Event (Page Location not set)

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-analytics, google-optimize

I've implemented a Google Optimize experiment as suggested with this article:

https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/6262084?hl=en&ref_topic=6197443

The experiment is set to run and I have targeted to the activation event and URL.

After I get to the correct state where I want to run the experiment I call

dataLayer.push({'event': 'optimize.activate.welcomeScreen'});

The experiment runs, I have tested on incognito Chrome browser and have seen the variant fire so I know that the push is sending the correct event to Optimize and modifying the DOM as expected.

However, I do not see the active user on the Experiment page as registered, and after letting the experiment run after a full day with a thousand users I see no active users shown.

I decided to troubleshoot so I used the Network tab in my developer console and I looked at the data non-interaction event being fired after the dataLayer call. I copied that to PostMan and I added a google analytics param "dl" and set it to my page location. Voila, the active user immediately shows up on my Optimize Experiment page.

Any clue why the "dl" param is not getting added? I've tried all kinds of things including doing a ga('set','location','http://myurl") and still no luck. I have wrapped the dataLayer call inside of setTimeOut to make sure DOM is properly loaded and that doesn't work either.

For completeness My analytics/optimize set up as follows

In the  I have

```
// Optimize snippet to prevent flashing
<script>(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
    h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
    (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
})(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
{'GTM-XXXXXX':true});</script>

// Google Analytics snippet
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');

        // For Google Optimize Tracking
        ga('require', 'GTM-XXXXXX');

        ga('send', 'pageview', {
            hitCallback: function () {
                console.log("sendGAPageView: successfully sent initial pageView for location:" + location);
            }});


</script>
```

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: see my answer below. best bet is to start with a completely fresh setup on both google analytics and optimize to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to say we finally got this working. It turns out the problem was our Google Analytics setup. We were using a filtered view so a lot of events weren't showing up. Make sure to not use any filters on your view when using with Optimize.

Comment: What does that mean?